# Something wrong with code in void

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Is something wrong with this code? Can't figure it out for a night!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    string email2 = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email;
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    string UserId2 = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = email2;
    TextBox3.Text = UserId2;
}
```

It says must have return type.

Comment: I guess there are more curly brackets that you don't show us here?

Comment: Perhaps you should step back to some beginning C# and programming books and tutorials if you're missing functions are surrounded with braces ...

Comment: Just some friendly advice: Telling us what you think what might be wrong is fairly important, rather than asking us to guess. If this code won't compile or is encountering a runtime error then post the error and stack trace. That way you avoid downvotes and folks will feel more inclined to help out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three things spring to mind:

- You haven't got an opening brace for the method
- Your `If` statement should be `if` - C# is case-sensitive
- You haven't got a closing brace for the method.

Comment: Skeet strikes again.  ;o

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string email2 = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email;
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        string UserId2 = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

        TextBox2.Text = email2;
        TextBox3.Text = UserId2;

    }
}
```